# Using the result of a VBA function inside a cell for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to some rows in an Excel table, based on a calculated value of one of the cells in that row (to be slightly more specific, I want to colour rows where the result of that formula is not equal to 1).

This is not working out, as the equality seems to not be satisfied.

My row setup, very simplified, is as follows:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some data in a cell | ... bunch more cells ... | cell containing a VBA function operating on "Some data in a cell", returning a number |

What I want is to be able to conditionally format the row, if the number in the last cell is not equal to 1 (or some other value to make this more general).

What seems to be the case to me is that for whatever reason, specifically values returned from VBA functions do not get "read" by whatever machinery is in Conditional Formatting in Excel.

If it is important, here's the function code verbatim. It used to return a String, hence things commented out.

```vb
Public Function IsInStock(Serial As String) As Integer
    Dim eventrange As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    
    Set eventrange = SheetEvents.Range("events[[Event type]:[Phone serial]]")
    
    Dim Row As Range
    ' Go through all events to determine final state of every phone
    For Each Row In eventrange.Rows
        Dim EventType As String
        EventType = Row.Cells.Item(1, 1).Value
        Dim eserial As String
        eserial = Row.Cells.Item(1, 2).Value
        
        If eserial = Serial Then
            Select Case EventType
            Case "Into stock"
                counter = counter + 1
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    IsInStock = counter '= Str(counter)
End Function
```

I made sure that I created a working rule first - correct range selected, correct relative references and so on.

When I set the conditional formatting rule to apply to cells in a row that has its first cell ("Some data") equal to one specific value, Excel immediately highlighted the correct rows.

When I set the conditional formatting rule to apply to cells in a row that had one of the in-between cells contain a specific value that was calculated by an Excel (non-VBA) formula, that worked as well.

That ensured that I had correct cell references and correct range to apply the rules to.

When I set the conditional formatting rule to use the VBA function I created directly, it did not work, but slowed down Excel immensely - as my function iterates over a table, and I assume it was run over every cell to check if it should be formatted, this caused the slowdown due to iterating over a table however many times is needed for every visible cell.

Therefore I added an extra column to the table, with `=FunctionIWrote($A1)` in the cells. The cells immediately filled with the correct result for each row.

I then created a rule that was exactly like the first attempts to make sure I had everything else correctly, but using this column instead of any other. This failed (the formula was exactly the same but with a different column number, something like `=$A1<>1`), as the cells that had the number 1 in them were ignored just like the ones that had a different number.

I tried enclosing the 1 in the formula in quotes, with same results.

I tried fiddling around with the return type of the function, changing it from String to Integer (I have read that functions to be used in cells are to always return a String but that might have been wrong), but had absolutely no results.

I even created yet another column, which just copied the value from the column that had the VBA function (literally `=$H1` which did indeed result in a column with identical values to the one next to it), thinking it was something weird with calculation order or something.

To sum up:

Formatting rule works if it refers to any other cells, including:

- Static cells with values manually written in
- Cells containing formulas that calculate something based on other cells

Formatting rule does NOT work if the VBA function is involved in any way:

- Using it directly as the "custom formula"
- Using it in a cell and pointing the format rule to that cell
- Using it in a cell and pointing the format rule to another cell that copies the value from that cell

Am I trying to do something that is completely impossible, or is there something I did not think of, or some other glaringly obvious mistake?

I have done a few searches, but all of them seem to relate to applying conditional formatting *using* VBA, and even in the suggested questions on here before submitting it was mostly the same. There was one single question that seemed similar, but it was about Access and did not translate to Excel at all.

As requested, here are screenshots of 3 versions of the same rule, showing that the only thing changed is the column it is checking. The first one uses the `C` column and compares it to `""` (blank). This works. The second one uses the `I` column and compares it to `1`. This does not work. The third screenshot uses the `J` column with the same comparison, also does not work.

[image: =$C1="" rule, working]

The `C` column has static data, some blanks and some not blanks. The screenshotted rule correctly highlights the `A` cell in every row that has it blank.

[image: =$I1=1 rule, not working]

The `I` column contains `=IsInStock(A2)` (as it is a table, and the references automatically get "continued" depending on the row, that part works). This displays in the cells as `0`'s, `1`'s, and sometimes other numbers. The screenshotted rule fails to highlight any rows that have a `1` in the `I` column, both exactly as screenshotted as well as with quotes around the `1`.

[image: =$J1=1 rule, not working]

The `J` column contains `=$J2` (as it is a table, and the references automatically get "continued" depending on the row, that part works). This displays in the cells as `0`'s, `1`'s, and sometimes other numbers, identical to the `I` column. The screenshotted rule fails to highlight any rows that have a `1` in the `J` column, both exactly as screenshotted as well as with quotes around the `1`.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I put some of the explanation in the middle, now I have recreated the rule again, with no results. I went and recreated everything again, I created a new rule with "Use Custom Formula...", input ``=$I1 = 1 `` (where *I* is the column with the function results). Nothing, no difference between cells that contain a ``1`` in the ``I`` column, and the ones that don't. I set the area to apply to to ``$A:$A`` to only highlight the first column cells. When I changed the ``I`` to a ``C`` and the check to ``""``, it did highlight the A cell in every row where ``C`` was blank as expected.

Comment: `Am I trying to do something that is completely impossible` - no, that's completely possible. There should be no difference in conditional formatting of VBA results versus Excel formulas. Putting the VBA function call itself into a CF rule is likely a bad idea indeed, but formatting over its results in a column is fine. There must be something wrong with your CF rule. As a side note though, your VBA function appears to be a poor man's replacement for [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

Comment: Hmmm, can you give us a screenshot of your rules in your sheet? I've retested with a similar poor man's replacement as GSerg calls it of a xlookup in a function looking up a value in a table with still a functional CF on it.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I hade added the requested screenshots of the 3 versions that I have tested (I have tested more than that, but those seemed the most relevant)

Comment: @GSerg I do not fully understand what the cause could be here yet. I might need to look into ``COUNTIF`` or maybe ``COUNTIFS``, does it allow to "filter" by multiple cell values for the row? My requirement is that it should count rows that have 1) a specific cell equal to a static value and 2) a different cell in the same row equal to (a value I am pulling out of the row in the table I want to format).

Comment: `The J column contains =$J2` - that doesn't sound right?

Comment: @GSerg yes, my bad, it is ``=$I2``, of course

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I used for my formula, it's just to complicate the function a bit in case referencing a range in a table or what have you would somehow cause an issue (covering all bases even though it should only be a returned value)

```
Function findCell(rng As Range)
    Dim mtch
    mtch = Application.Match(rng.Value, Range("A2:A11"), 0)
    If Not IsError(mtch) Then
        findCell = Application.Index(Range("B2:B11"), mtch)
    Else
        findCell = "NonFound"
    End If
End Function
```

With the conditional formatting like so:
[image]

Can you spot your error with this visualization? If it still doesn't work, let me know :)

I've now also tested with the formulas being used in the same table, with it going over the range A:A and it still works, I cannot reproduce your problem it seems.

Comment: I will need to do more testing and probably create a minimal example and then compare things bit by bit to see what is actually going wrong. So far, the most useful thing I learned here is that it *should* work and the problem is not "this is literally not possible to do this way".

Comment: Okay, apologies for not getting back to this right away - I am suspecting that *something* went wrong with the calculations somewhere as I have been making some changes here and there to the exact setup of the columns that use the VBA function, at some point (I believe I changed the cell reference as it was pointing to the one above the intended one due to a typo) the column filled itself with numerical values (slowly) and the formatting rule suddenly worked. I have noticed that it takes a long time to update the calculation results every time I change something, though...

Comment: I eventually ended up ditching the idea altogether, and eventually redo it with native excel functions. I am not sure what the correct SO etiquette would be here - my problem has kinda resolved itself, and eventually I decided to use something entirely different for unrelated reasons. And it is both your comments as well as some from @GSerg that pushed me to do more testing knowing that it should be possible, and gave me ideas for those alternative options.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with "closing a question" or considering it "resolved" when it resolved itself without an answer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm just happy you got it to work in the end.